# a div loading entire web site in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5

I am trying to load a page like

```
   http://localhost/dropbox/joomla_25/index.php?option=com_helloworld&control=add&task=new1
```

but a div in index.php page ( in templates ) is loading entire site ..
and I am working on joomla 2.5

help me please

Comment: Please share template relative code

Comment: Here is the url...


http://myjoom25.byethost17.com/joomla16/index.php?option=com_hello&control=add&task=new1

when i am inserted jquery tabs ..entire site displaying in the tabs